# Not able to set up gcc in aws sagemaker notebook

Tags: conda, amazon-sagemaker, facebook-prophet

I am working in a jupyter notebook in aws sagemaker and want to use prophet for time-series forecast. I am using the conda_python3 kernel. According to the installation instruction from https://facebook.github.io/prophet/docs/installation.html#python I need to set up gcc before installing prophet, but when I try '%conda install gcc', I get the error message that the environment is inconsistent.

Does anyone know how to solve this issue?

**Error message:**

Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: /
The environment is inconsistent, please check the package plan carefully
The following packages are causing the inconsistency:

- conda-forge/noarch::nbclient==0.5.2=pyhd8ed1ab_0
- conda-forge/linux-64::matplotlib==3.3.4=py36h5fab9bb_0
- conda-forge/noarch::qdarkstyle==2.8.1=pyhd8ed1ab_2
- conda-forge/linux-64::scikit-image==0.16.2=py36hb3f55d8_0
- conda-forge/noarch::python-language-server==0.36.2=pyhd8ed1ab_0
- conda-forge/linux-64::widgetsnbextension==3.5.1=py36h5fab9bb_4
- conda-forge/noarch::flake8==3.8.4=py_0
- conda-forge/noarch::ipywidgets==7.6.3=pyhd3deb0d_0
- conda-forge/noarch::typing-extensions==3.7.4.3=0
- conda-forge/noarch::path.py==12.5.0=0
- conda-forge/noarch::dask==2021.2.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
- conda-forge/noarch::nbformat==5.1.2=pyhd8ed1ab_1
- conda-forge/linux-64::path==15.1.2=py36h5fab9bb_0
- conda-forge/linux-64::nbconvert==6.0.7=py36h5fab9bb_3
- conda-forge/linux-64::distributed==2021.2.0=py36h5fab9bb_0
- conda-forge/noarch::anaconda-client==1.7.2=py_0
- conda-forge/noarch::aioitertools==0.7.1=pyhd8ed1ab_0
- conda-forge/linux-64::matplotlib-base==3.3.4=py36hd391965_0
- conda-forge/linux-64::pluggy==0.13.1=py36h5fab9bb_4
- conda-forge/noarch::black==20.8b1=py_1
- conda-forge/linux-64::blaze==0.11.3=py36_0
- conda-forge/noarch::pyls-spyder==0.3.2=pyhd8ed1ab_0
- conda-forge/noarch::odo==0.5.1=py_1
- conda-forge/linux-64::keyring==22.0.1=py36h5fab9bb_0
- conda-forge/noarch::anaconda-project==0.9.1=pyhd8ed1ab_0
- conda-forge/noarch::importlib_metadata==3.7.0=hd8ed1ab_0
- conda-forge/linux-64::jupyter==1.0.0=py36h5fab9bb_6
- conda-forge/noarch::jupyterlab_server==2.3.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
- conda-forge/noarch::seaborn-base==0.11.1=pyhd8ed1ab_1
- conda-forge/noarch::imageio==2.9.0=py_0
- conda-forge/noarch::numpydoc==1.1.0=py_1
- conda-forge/linux-64::yarl==1.6.3=py36h8f6f2f9_1
- conda-forge/noarch::jsonschema==3.2.0=py_2
- conda-forge/noarch::flask==1.1.2=pyh9f0ad1d_0
- conda-forge/noarch::seaborn==0.11.1=hd8ed1ab_1
- conda-forge/noarch::helpdev==0.7.1=pyhd8ed1ab_0
- conda-forge/linux-64::nb_conda==2.2.1=py36h5fab9bb_4
- conda-forge/noarch::nbclassic==0.2.6=pyhd8ed1ab_0
- conda-forge/noarch::sphinx==3.5.1=pyhd8ed1ab_0
- conda-forge/noarch::jupyterlab_launcher==0.13.1=py_2
- conda-forge/linux-64::spyder==4.2.0=py36h5fab9bb_0
- conda-forge/linux-64::importlib-metadata==3.7.0=py36h5fab9bb_0
- conda-forge/linux-64::pytest==6.2.2=py36h5fab9bb_0
- conda-forge/noarch::pyls-black==0.4.6=pyh9f0ad1d_0
  / ^C
  failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.

CondaError: KeyboardInterrupt

Note: you may need to restart the kernel to use updated packages.

Answer (score 0):

Have you confirmed GCC is not installed already?  I ran the below on a SageMaker Notebook Instance with conda_python3 kernel selected.

```
!gcc --version
gcc (GCC) 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-28)
Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

Comment: Thank you! Yes, actually, it is already installed with the same version that you have. But when I continue with %conda install -c conda-forge prophet to install prophet, then again I get the same error message as above (environment is inconsistent). I checked, if prophet is installed already with !prophet --version and it is not.

Comment: Can you try the steps here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60668635/import-problem-for-facebook-prophet-on-aws-sagemaker

Comment: I have now tried it and, unfortunately, the problem with the inconsistent environment persists. I activated the python3 environment and then used conda install -c conda-forge prophet to install prophet:  sh-4.2$ source init
sh: source: /sbin/init: cannot execute binary file
sh-4.2$ 
sh-4.2$ source activate python3
(python3) sh-4.2$ conda install -c conda-forge prophet --yes